# send notification when phone boots up

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make an android app in kotlin that sends me a notification every time the date change, the screen is turned on or the phone boots up

I tried to use a BroadcastReceiver to send the notification but it didn't work.
here is the BroadcastReceiver

```
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat


class SendNotification: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED || intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON || intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED){
            println(intent)
            println(context)
            val hours = TOTKTime.getHours()
            val days = TOTKTime.getDays()
            val notificationManager = context?.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "TOTK").setContentText("about ${days}days, ${hours} hours left until TOTK's release").setContentTitle("time until tears of the kingdom").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_totk).build()
            notificationManager.notify(1, notification)
        }
    }

}
```

the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:name=".app"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_totk_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TOKTTimer"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".SendNotification" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and I created the notification channel

```
import android.app.Application
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context

class app: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            "TOTK",
            "Time till TOKT",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        )
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a similar functionality by launching a `Service` after a `reboot`

Try this:

In your `SendNotification` class, launch a `Service`

```
public class SendNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyBootService.class);
          serviceIntent.putExtra("service_call", "RebootReceiver");
          context.startService(serviceIntent);
       }
}
```

Then, define your `MyBootService` as follows:

```
  public class MyBootService extends IntentService {

         @Override
         protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
             String intentType = intent.getExtras().getString("service_call");
             if(intentType == null) return;
             if(intentType.Equals("RebootReceiver"))
                  //Do reboot stuff
             //handle other types of intents, like a notification.
         }
     }
```

My **AndroidManifest.xml** looks like this:

```
<service android:name="com.kb.service.MyBootService"/>
...
<receiver android:name="com.kb.receiver.SendNotification">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
...
 <uses-permission 
  android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

**P.S:** I had used Java back then but you can write the same in Kotlin as well.